# Generating Dynamic Form from JSON file with infinite tiers of nesting

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I created a mechanism for my questionnaires that I'm making into an `Angular Form`.  So far I have everything working the way I want which you can take a look at here https://plnkr.co/edit/nBpriDOgC88Fo2WMpM6A?p=preview

So far all I've seen in regards to creating dynamic forms is pretty simple and strait forward with a couple of fields and no conditional situations, meanwhile I have groups of questions nested 3-4 tiers deep and fields in my database used strictly for logical purposes.

I studied the `Dynamic Forms` docs on `Angular.io` again particularly this chunk of code
    toFormGroup(questions: QuestionBase[] ) {
        let group: any = {};

```
    questions.forEach(question => {
      group[question.key] =
          question.required ? new FormControl(question.value || '', Validators.required): new FormControl(question.value || '');
    });
    return new FormGroup(group);
  }
```

As they're using it to bind their mock data  I figured this would be a good starting place.

This is how I've shaped my data model

```
export class QuestionPrimative {
    question    : string;
    id          : string;
    name        : string;
    ctrlName?   : string;
    lowExtreme? : string;
    hiExtreme?  : string;
    template    : string;
}

export class Answer {
    answer      : string;
    id          : string;
    trigger?    : string;
    formctrl?   : string;
}

export class QuestionBase extends QuestionPrimative {
    answers?    : Answer[];
}

export class MicroQuestions {
    activate    : string;
    questions   : Question[];
    childgroup  : string;
}

export class Question extends QuestionBase {
    micros?     : MicroQuestions[];
}

export class QuestionSection {
    name        : string;
    questions   : Question[];
}

export class QuestionnaireBody{
    sections: QuestionSection[];
}
```

The rationality behind the shape of my data goes as follows

```
//The data when it iterates into Component
question    : string;           // the question to be asked
id          : string;           // id attribute for HTML
name        : string;           // name attribute for HTML
ctrlName?   : string;           // form control name
template    : string;           // matches *ngIf on appropriate chunk of HTML
answers?    : Answer[];         // available answers if multiple choice
lowExtreme? : string;           // low extreme if question involves rating
hiExtreme?  : string;           // hi extreme for rating
micros?     : MicroQuestions[]; // if more questions are available

//if answers are available.....
answer      : string;           // the answer
id          : string;           // id attribute for HTML
trigger?    : string;           // used to trigger another tier of questions
formctrl?   : string;           // if element needs to be a form control

//if there is another tier of questions ......
activate?   : string;           // matches with the 'trigger' in the answer to know to load
questions?  : QuestionBase[];   // the next tier of questions
```

I'm attempting to do build the entire form inside of my service file which looks like this

```
import { Injectable, OnInit }       from '@angular/core';

import { FormBuilder, FormControl,
         FormGroup, FormArray }     from '@angular/forms';

import { QuestionSection }          from '../../data-types/question-section';
import { Question }                 from '../../data-types/question';

import { Response, Http }           from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }               from 'rxjs/observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';



@Injectable()

export class QuestionService implements OnInit {

    QuestionnaireData: any;
    QuestinnaireLoad: FormGroup;



    constructor(private http: Http, private fbuild: FormBuilder){
        this.QuestionnaireLoad = this.fbuild.group({
            sections: this.fbuild.array(this.buildSections(data: this.QuestionnaireData.sections) ||'');
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(){ this.getData(); }

    getData() {
        this.QuestionnaireData = this.http.get('app/questionnaire/questions.json')
        .map(res => res.json())

        return this.QuestionnaireData;
    }


    buildSections(data){
        let group: any = {};

        data.forEach(section =>{
            group[section.name]         = name      : section ? section.name: '';
            group[section.questions]    = questions : new FormArray(this.buildQuestionnaire(quest: section.questions) ||'');
        });

        return new FormGroup(group);
    }

    buildQuestion(quest){
        let group: any = {};

        sect.forEach(ques =>{
            group[ques.question]    = question  : ques ? ques.question: '';
            group[ques.id]          = id        : ques ? ques.id: '';
            group[ques.name]        = name      : ques ? ques.name: '';
            group[ques.ctrlName]    = ctrlName  : ques ? ques.ctrlName: '';
            group[ques.template]    = template  : ques ? ques.template: '';
            group[ques.lowExtreme]  = lowExtreme: ques ? ques.hiExtreme: '';
            group[ques.hiExtreme]   = hiExtreme : ques ? ques.lowExtreme: '';
            group[ques.answers]     = answers   : new FormArray(this.buildAnswers(answ: ques.answers) ||'');
            group[ques.micros]      = micros: new FormGroup(this.buildMicros(mic: ques.micros) ||'');
        });

        return new FormGroup(group);
    }

    buildAnswer(answ){
        let group:any = {};

        answ.forEach(item =>{
            group[item.answer]  = answer  : item ? item.answer: '';
            group[item.id]      = id      : item ? item.id: '';
            group[item.trigger] = trigger : item ? item.trigger: '';
            group[item.ctrlName]= ctrlName: item ? item.ctrlName: '';
        });

        return new FormGroup(group);
    }

    buildMicros(mic){
        let group: any = {};

        mic.forEach(micro =>{
            group[micro.activate]  = activate  : micro ? micro.activate: '';
            group[micro.childGroup]= childGroup: micro ? micro.childGroup: '';
            group[micro.questions]= new FormArray(this.buildQuestion(quest: micro.questions) || '');
        });

        return new FormGroup(group);
    }
}
```

So far I'm getting an error telling me data isn't defined, I'm not even sure if this is what I should even be trying to do.  Some of the fields I want to simply be fields, rather than controls, which is why I'm only making a few controls, groups and arrays here and there.  At the end of the day I want to be able to make any `.json` file shaped in the manner I outlined before and have everything automatically work itself out.  How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your observables are not being handled correctly and you're doing things out of order.  All you've done is set your data variable to a cold observable stream and then you never use.  Observables need to be subscribed to in order to activate.  You also run your build function in your constructor before you even define the variable in onInit. You need to restructure like:

```
private QuestinnaireLoadSource: BehaviorSubject<FormGroup> = new BehaviorSubject<FormGroup>(null);
questionaireLoad$: Observable<FormGroup> = this.QuestinnaireLoadSource.asObservable().filter(e => !!e);

constructor(private http: Http, private fbuild: FormBuilder){ }

ngOnInit(){ this.loadData(); }

loadData() {
   this.http.get('app/questionnaire/questions.json')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(data => this.fbuild.group({sections: this.fbuild.array(this.buildSections(data.sections))})
      .subscribe(this.QuestinnaireLoadSource);
}
```

I've done a lot here. I've exposed your question form group as an observable of a behavior subject.  This way components that need it can just subscribe to the behavior subject and it will get to them when it's ready (whether they instantiate at any point between the data being fetched from the server to the mapping being finished or any point after). I've exposed an observable instead of the subject itself because the subject itself should only be mutated in very controlled ways through a well defined API, this keeps your app maintainable and clean.

I've changed the get method to a load method that subscribes to your http call so that it actually triggers and then maps the response into the form group and doesn't save it as state because it isn't needed anymore, if it is you should pass it through the observable rather than creating state.  Statefulness like you have is messy and hard to debug when it breaks and hard to reason about when it's loading or when consumers should be able to use it.  Observable streams control your flow much better.

Comment: so you're saying I should get rid of all the individual functions and just go with the code above?  I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what's going on.  What is `BehaviorSubject` by the way?

Comment: how does this go all the way down to the `micros` level in my data?

Comment: The map function in your http observable calls the top level form group building function which parses your data and transforms it into a form group and then broadcasts it to your behavior subject so other consumers can find it.  However, you're putting the cart very far before the horse here. You're getting into advanced form building but your foundation isn't there yet.  You should spend some time learning the basics of Angular if you don't know how to operate observables/subjects and rxjs in general.  The reactive forms you're building are totally based on observables.

Comment: I'm not saying to get rid of all your parsing functions, I clearly call one of them in the second map operator, I just didn't include them for brevity and as I didn't edit them. Though in truth none of it will work because you haven't actually constructed ANY form controls, and the || '' syntax is only for declaring a default value of blank string in from controls, it will fail on form groups or form arrays as it isn't a valid parameter.

Comment: Is it ok that there is no `ngOnInit` hook for service?